# Selective Expansion During Boost Graph Library Search

Tags: c++, boost, graph

I have a boost graph implemented as an adjacency list and I'm searching through the graph using the `dijkstra_shortest_paths` function.  I've stored a cost in the edges and some position information in the vertices.  I've also stored some additional information in the edges such that the information stored in an incoming edge of a vertex informs which outgoing edges must be expanded.  Essentially, I want to search only a subgraph of the original graph by enabling the `dijkstra_shortest_paths` function to make decisions about which edges need to be searched over. Is there a way that this can be implemented with the boost graph library?  The closest thing I found was using a [Dijkstra Visitor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/graph/doc/DijkstraVisitor.html) but I'm not sure how to implement this.  Has anyone done this before?  Could you give an example?

Comment: You can indeed override the actions in the visitor, or if the predicates are static use  a `filtered_graph` adaptor

Comment: @sehe I've taken a look at the `filtered_graph` documentation and I'm struggling to figure out how to apply it to my problem.  My graph is directed and connected.  I need to be able to know the incoming edge to a node in order to determine if the outgoing edge can be filtered out.  It doesn't seem like `filtered_graph` can be used in that way.  Can it?

Comment: I have done examples using filtered graph on this site. You can search via my profile.